# Accepts nested attributes convention for mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I'm trying to create a form with nested attributes using mongoid. My models have the following code:

```
def Company
  field :name

  has_many :users, autosave: true, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :users
end

def User
  belongs_to :company
  has_one :profile
end

def Profile
  belongs_to :user
end
```

The params that are returned from the form are in the following order:

```
"company"=>
  {"users_attributes"=>
    {"0"=>
      {"profile_attributes"=>
        {"first_name"=>"123123abcd123", "last_name"=>"abcd123123123"},
       "email"=>"abcd@abcd.com123123123",
       "password"=>"123123123123",
       "password_confirmation"=>"123123123123"}},
   "name"=>"abcd123123123",
   "subdomain"=>"abcd123123123"}
```

Calling Company.create(params[:company]) seems to work, however it is not properly creating the user object. When I do company.users I can see that object, BUT when I do User.find, that document is not available. Reading the documentations I realized that the params should be passed in the following way:

```
"company"=>
  {"users_attributes"=>
    [{"profile_attributes"=>
       {"first_name"=>"123123123", "last_name"=>"123123123"},
      "email"=>"testin321@gmail.com",
      "password"=>"123123",
      "password_confirmation"=>"123123"}],
   "name"=>"abcd123123123",
   "subdomain"=>"abcd123123123"}
```

Note the subtle difference of using an array for users_attributes instead of a hash. This works right, but then it doesn't seem quite out of the box like it is with Active Record (and how it should be in something like in rails). I don't want to take the params hash and modify the data to make it follow certain conventions. Is there a better way, am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

if you can name the `inputs as user_attributes[]` that would make the array.

So instead of having `user_attributes[0][profile_attributes]` (I think you have something like this)

Make it to have `user_attributes[][profile_attributes]`

Answer (score 0):

Could you post the code for the form? Then we can work on getting down to the reason it's formatted a certain way. (This should be a comment, but I am will to provide an answer once there are more details regarding the question.)

On a side note from your issue with the form in the view. I notice you are trying to create a company and it's nested users and the user and it's nested profile attributes as well. If you expect user to accept nested attributes for profile than you need to put that in the User model.

```
def User
  belongs_to :company
  has_one :profile, dependent: destroy, autosave: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile
end
```

That may solve your problem, the error might arise from the User trying to mass-assign profile attributes without explicit instructions to do so.